# How to parse many characters except few in the parentheses?

Tags: parsing, elm

The best way to parse any character except few, is to use `noneOf` combinator, 
Unfortunately it doesn't work if I combine it in the following way:

```
Combine.parse (Combine.parens <| Combine.many <| Combine.Char.noneOf ['"', '\\']) "()"

Err ((),{ data = "()", input = "", position = 2 },["expected \")\""])
: Result.Result
    (Combine.ParseErr ()) (Combine.ParseOk () (List Char))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `noneOf` results in that parser consuming all characters *including* the closing parenthesis. Since the inner portion consumes the closing paren, the `Combine.parens` parser will not see the closing paren. You need to cause the `many <| noneOf ...` parser to halt on a closing parenthesis.

Consider adding the closing parenthesis to the list of characters in `noneOf`:

```elm
Combine.parse (Combine.parens <| Combine.many <| Combine.Char.noneOf ['"', '\\', ')']) "()"
```